# update file in a subdirectory from a list- filename gotten from csv

Tags: python, csv

I've got a python script that pulls a filename from a csv file, and updates that file by adding a value to a field within the file. My problem is the file I need to update is actually in a subdirectory, with a folder name completely unrelated to the file I need to update.

my .csv list is like this:

```
file1, fieldx, value
file2, fieldx, value
```

and the files are in folders like this:

```
abcd/file1
efgh/file2
```

How can I update my code to find the file within the folder? I'm really new to Python, and I know it involves either glob, glob2, or os.walk, but I'm not sure how to nest / loop since I'm pulling the filename value from the .csv.

Here's my code:

```
import csv

startfile = raw_input("Please enter the name of the csv file: ")
with open(startfile, 'r') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
changelist = list(reader)

for x in changelist:
linnum = 0
fname=x[0]+".xml"
fieldlookup = x[1]

with open(fname) as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if fieldlookup in line:
            linnum = num
f.close()

f = open(fname, 'r') 
lines = f.readlines()
if linnum > 0:
    lines[linnum-1] = "  <"+fieldlookup+">"+str(x[2])+"</"+fieldlookup+">\n"
    f.close()

f = open(fname, 'w')
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()

print "success!"+str(x[0])+"\n"
```

Comment: The answer depends a bit on whether (a) you are guaranteed that the file  does exist somewhere under the one given parent dir and (b) whether a given file exists only *once* in all possible subdirs.

Comment: Yes, it exists somewhere in one of the folders. Yes, it exists only once.

Answer (score 0):

If there exist only one level of subdirs, you should be able to do it just  by:

```
import glob
... 
fname=x[0]+".xml" 
real_fname=glob.glob("./*/"+fname)
```

And use real_fname afterwards. If you need cross platform compatibility you could use also os.path.join instead of +.